# When is a quotient group $G/H$ abelian?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

So clearly if $G$ is abelian and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $G/H$ is abelian since $$xH.yH =(xy)H=(yx)H=yH.xH$$
But is there cases when this quotient group is abelian without the group G being abelian?

What I came up with is that for $(xy)H=(yx)H$ to be true then $(xy)^{-1}(yx)\in H$ must be satisfied, for all $x,y \in G$. Is this correct ? And any examples to this?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, this is the universal property of the derived subgroup.  Note that $H=G$ is always a rather trivial example.

Comment: Your second paragraph kind of points to the idea of [abelianization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as mentioned in the comments you can always take the quotient by the so-called *commutator subgroup*.   That is, the group generated by all commutators $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ of elements of $G$.

This quotient is always abelian,  and is referred to as the *abelianization* of $G$.

Now, the answer to your title question is that the quotient $G/H$ will be abelian iff $H$ contains the commutator, aka the "first derived subgroup":  $[G,G]\le H$.

Comment: never came across abelianization until now , Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> But is there cases when this quotient group is abelian without the group G being abelian?

Ans: Consider $G:=Q_8$, [the quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group)  and $H:=\{\pm1,\pm i\}$.Then $G/H$ is Abelian whereas $G$ is not!

Comment: What is the Q8 group?

Comment: @EdenHazard Quaternion group, generated by $1,i,j,k$ and their negatives.

Comment: $Q_8$ is the quaternion group containing eight elements: $\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k$, following the rules $$ij = k, jk = i, ki = j$$ $$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$$

Comment: Thanks a lot guys 

Answer (score 2):

Use the notion of the commutator subgroup to prove the following characterization:

> Let $G$ be any group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup. Denote the commutator subgroup of $G$ by $[G,G]$.
>
> Then the quotient $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $[G,G]\le H$.

This gives an easy way of identifying whether quotients will be abelian or not, given that you know something about $[G,G]$.